# Viper mapping environment variable to struct member

Tags: go, viper-go

Here's my `config.yaml` file

```
server:
  port: 5000
```

here's my logic to unmarshal using viper

```
type Configurations struct {
    Server ServerConfig
}

type ServerConfig struct {
    Port int
}

// LoadConfig reads configuration from file or environment variables.
func LoadConfig(path string) (config Configurations, err error) {
    viper.AddConfigPath(path)
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("yaml")

    viper.AutomaticEnv()

    err = viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&config)
    return
}
```

I have set env variable `export PORT=9000`, now my question is how can I map the environmental variable `PORT` to `Configurations.ServerConfig.Port`.
I would like to have config file with default values for dev and would like my app to read/override config from env variables on production, how can I achieve this using viper.

I see following options

1. set `SERVER_PORT` and then use replacer like below to unmarshal it to struct

```
replacer := strings.NewReplacer(".", "_")
viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer(replacer)
```

2. [Go viper .yaml values environment variables override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756532/go-viper-yaml-values-environment-variables-override)

But I would like to map variable `PORT` to the struct member, probably because my hosting service provider sets `PORT` env variable, and I cannot use 2nd point because I would like to have yaml for default values.

Comment: Why you are not setting `yaml:"server"` and `yaml:"port"` for your fields, then set the `SERVER_PORT` evn?

Comment: As mentioned in the question my hosting provider sets. PORT by default and I cannot overwrite so `SERVER_PORT` is not an option. also I want to explore how I can bind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `viper.BindEnv(string...) error` to bind specific environment variables to configuration.

From [Working with Environment Variables](https://github.com/spf13/viper#working-with-environment-variables):

> BindEnv takes one or more parameters. The first parameter is the key name, the rest are the name of the environment variables to bind to this key. If more than one are provided, they will take precedence in the specified order.

Here the configuration key for the port is `server.port`, and the environment variable `PORT` should bind to it.

```
...
viper.AutomaticEnv()


err = viper.BindEnv("server.port", "PORT")
if err != nil {
    return
}


err = viper.ReadInConfig()
...
```

With this change in place a call like `PORT=9999 ./yourbinary` picks up `PORT` and writes it into `server.port`. From there, it will be unmarshalled into your struct.